# Want to convert CSV File into Formdata in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, form-data, mobile-development

Hy, I'm new in react-native. I'm trying to my CSV file into formdata using **FormData**. But it's confusing or not work according to me.
The app I'm trying to create already created for the web in reactJS.
Here code of web(reactJS) is working :

```
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("file", csvFile);
```

and button is:

```
<Form.File>
                <Form.File.Input
                  accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                  type="file"
                  component="span"
                  onChange={handleFile}
                  name="file"
                />
 </Form.File>
```

In react, we append the file it's saved in **file**, which is the value of the name attribute in the button.

**Code for react-native**
Now in react native I try this something like this:

```
  let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({type: "text/csv"});
        const dataFile ={
            "file":result
          }
         let formData = new FormData();
         formData.append("file", dataFile);
```

**Button**

```
  <TouchableOpacity>
                <Button title="upload your file" color="black" onPress={pickDocument}  />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I use **DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()** to get the file. But according to me, there is no props name for the button in react-native.
Now question is that how I can formdata.append() it. like web do in web

Comment: What is the output of `handleFile`

Comment: It's just receiving a CSV file.